# Implementing Global Search for identifying Duplicate Records

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am implementing a VF page which will be on the record contact detail page. I am making use of current record id to pull the matched records on to this VF page. Controller class for the VF page:

```
...
public Contact curCont{get; set;}
public List<Contact> relatedList {get; set;}
...
List<Contact> conList =[SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact 
                            WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id')];
    
    if(conList.size() > 0){
        curCont = conList[0];
        
        relatedList = [SELECT Id, Name, Email, AccountId
                       FROM Contact
                       WHERE (Email =: curCont.Email OR Name =: curCont.Name) 
                       AND Id !=: curCont.Id];
     }
return relatedList;
...
```

This does the job very well, but my only concern is: We may have Contact records with very slight differences, such as: Roger Williams is same person as Roger J. Williams. End users might end up creating so many records in this fashion.

How can I query all these extra-character-added records(the way **Salesforce Global Search** functions) and display on to my page, that way I can provide the end users extra capability to identify duplicates more further.

**Update:**

Current Global Search results when I search for word: **john**

[image]

If I open up contact: **John Test 1**, my vf page pulls only two records based on my above query: `(Email =: curCont.Email OR Name =: curCont.Name)`

[image]

**Problem trying to solve:**

How can I get the same results as from the Global Search results? Like 'john' bring up all contacts that has **john** in any part of the name?

Comment: Have you considered using a SOSL query?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm

Comment: No. I am unfamiliar with that. Could you please provide me any sample query which retrieves me the wildcard matched list of records?

Comment: There are examples of how to use wildcards in the "Example Text Searches" section of the document @DavidCheng linked.

Comment: @DavidReed I see those examples. But they are seems like generic and sticks to static data. How are those examples fit my current scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to add a little more context here in the hope of being more useful.

Global Search is analogous to **SOSL**, the query format Salesforce provides for free-text searches that span one or more objects and whole sets of fields. SOSL is highly applicable for doing "fuzzy" searches, like in the Salesforce Global Search function. When you perform a SOSL search, you specify some broad set of fields (or `IN ALL FIELDS` to cover everything SOSL can index) to *search*, and a much more limited set of fields to *return*. In the examples below, the field names in parentheses after the object name are the fields being returned to you in your search results.

The **SOQL** query you're currently using can also provide a certain level of fuzzy matching, but it is implemented very differently. A SOQL query only matches against a specific object, and matches specific fields in exactly the way it's told to - so if you utilize a wildcard search like

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE '%John%'
```

(where `%` is the wildcard character), you'll get back any contact whose Name field contains `John`, at any position. Conversely, you will *not* get back a Contact whose Email field contains `John` - you would need to run a separate query, or `OR` together criteria, to get that behavior.

You can perform Dynamic SOSL (and similarly Dynamic SOQL) to use user input in the `WHERE` or `FIND` clauses of your queries. You do this by constructing a query as a string using either static or dynamic search parameters, and wild-cards, in Apex, and passing it to the `Database.query` or `Search.query` method.

The examples below show how to do this for SOSL, because it seems to be closer to what your objective is. You can also construct queries using strings in a similar manner to be run as SOQL.

```
String q = 'FIND \'John*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(FirstName, LastName)';
List<List<SObject>> results = Search.query(q);
```

or, with dynamic data:

(Note that `searchTerm` represents whatever Apex variable you are using to store your desired search term).

```
String q = 'FIND \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(FirstName, LastName)';
List<List<SObject>> results = Search.query(q);
```

SOSL gives you back a `List<List<SObject>>`, since you can return results from more than one type of object. The lists are in the same order as they are listed in the `RETURNING` clause. In a situation where you're only returning one kind of object, you can extract the first `List<Sobject>` and cast it to a list of the appropriate type like this (where `results` is as above).

```
List<Contact> contacts = (List<Contact>)results[0];
```

This can then be acted upon as any other `List<Contact>`, including iteration.

For more details on Dynamic SOSL, I'd recommend the [Apex Developer Guide under Dynamic SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm). There's also a great reference [on wildcards](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm#topic-title) from the SOSL and SOQL Reference, which covers all aspects of search syntax.

Now, which of these solutions do you need to adopt? I'm not sure. Adding more detail to your objectives in your question might help. If what you want is a fuzzy match on one or two fields on a single object, SOQL is going to be the way to go. If, conversely, you want a Global Search-style, broad-based search across multiple fields and one (or more) object(s), you probably want SOSL. Either way, you will likely need to construct a dynamic query.

Comment: What's **searchTerm** here? I am not passing any parameters to my controller's method either. How to get the condition that I had in my SOQL i.e. `WHERE (Email =: curCont.Email OR Name =: curCont.Name) 
                       AND Id !=: curCont.Id`. 
Providing a generic answer creates more confusion than reaching to a solution.

Comment: Mr. Evans, I don't mean to be disrespectful, but you seem awfully prickly. Could you tone it down a little? This is not a forum where code is written *for* you and your situation. You asked how to perform a global-style search, which uses SOSL, and that's what I'm aiming to cover here. Your query is not meaningfully translatable into SOSL, and as such you would have to evaluate how the SOSL works and make some changes to your code.

Comment: Well, you need to understand that, I am not asking for you to write any code here. I am just wondering how I can make use of the available resources. A person from a different background cannot easily figure out things in a new environment. I've just asked few questions on what/how to make use of your solution. If you cannot provide such(from your own answer), it's no point of answering here. My apologies, if you've received my previous message in a wrong perspective.

Comment: If you have provided some more context to that **searchTerm** and other details to implement SOSL using my current approach, that would've been a great help. You could've provided your thought process when you mention such terms in your answer. Without which, there is no easy way to understand for a person who knows nothing.

Comment: I'm happy to try to help, and I've added some additional context in my answer. You may also want to edit your question to provide more specificity on what the desired behavior looks like.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my concern. I appreciate your time and effort in answering.

Comment: Question: I get to this using another method by passing parameters(Firstname and Lastname): `List<List<SObject>> results = Search.query(q);`. Now how can I loop through all the results? I have tried this which throws me an error: `if(results != null){
                for(Contact c: results ){
                    contactList.add(new contactWrapper(c));
                } 
            }`. I know I cannot loop this way. Can you help me with right direction?

Comment: I made an edit to clarify this piece.

Comment: Perfect. That's working well.