# How to implement Dynamic SOSL with 'Contains' keyword

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-sosl

This is an embedded VF page on the Contact detail page. 
I have this **SOSL** query to display all the related contact records on every Contact detail page. But for few contacts, email field(of *Parent Contact*) is empty, thus it gets me all the irrelevant records.

```
String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + fName + ' AND ' + lName + ' OR ' + email +
                     '*\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Name,Id,Email,AccountId,Account.Name,Phone,MobilePhone 
                     WHERE Email != null AND Id !=\''+ conId + '\')';
```

I assume, because of this empty **Email** field(Parent's), I am pulling all the records via my query. I am thinking, with the use of **Contains** keyword, I can get rid of irrelevant data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Note:** This is a Wildcard search implementation.

Comment: You don't need dynamic SOSL for this purpose. Consider using inline SOSL instead.

Comment: Well, I had this question long ago: [Implementing Global Search for identifying Duplicate Records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211002/implementing-global-search-for-identifying-duplicate-records). I am already into this implementation since then.

Comment: And I am not familiar with the Inline SOSL too. : |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline SOSL is almost always the most appropriate way to do a search. It's just like inline SOQL, but the syntax changes slightly. You'll need to do some pretty complicated footwork just to get the three parameters together:

```
String searchTerm = '';
if(fName != null) {
  if(lName != null) {
    searchTerm += '('+fName+' AND '+lName+')';
  } else {
    searchTerm += fName;
  }
} else {
  if(lName != null) {
    searchTerm += lName;
  }
}
if(email != null) {
  if(searchTerm != '') {
    searchTerm += ' OR ';
  }
  searchTerm += email;
}
Contact[] results = [FIND :searchTerm 
                     IN ALL FIELDS
                     RETURNING Contact(
                       Name,Id,Email,AccountId,Account.Name,Phone,MobilePhone
                       WHERE Email <> NULL AND Id <> :conId][0];
```

`CONTAINS` is a keyword used for multi-select pick list fields (e.g. `MyCustomField__c CONTAINS 'ABC'`). This won't help you. You may need additional tweaking, but this should get you started.

Comment: For wildcard search, can I use this way?: `[FIND :searchTerm* 
                     IN ALL FIELDS ....`

Comment: @AustinEvans Put the `*` in the searchTerm variable. It's literally the same syntax as typing into the global search bar.

Comment: Sure, I got that by appending to the searchTerm variable itself. Awesome man, you did answered my two questions in this single question. You are a LEGEND.